# Como customizar ListView em tempo de execução?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-berlin

Estou com um problema em um exemplo no qual eu preciso adicionar um `Text` ao `ListView` que vem de um XML por código porém não aparece quando executo. Roda, mas aparece alguns *warnings* de depreciação e não aparece o campo. Vejam abaixo:

```
procedure TfrmUFC.LinkFillControlToField1FillingListItem(Sender: TObject;
  const AEditor: IBindListEditorItem);
var
   Item: TListViewItem;
   TextoIdade: TListItemText;
   TextField: TField;
begin
   Item := lvwLutadores.Items[AEditor.CurrentIndex];
   TextoIdade := Item.Objects.FindObject('Idade') as TListItemText;
   TextField := BindSourceDB1.DataSet.FindField('Idade');
   TextoIdade.Text := TextField.AsString;
end;
```

*Warning*:

```
[dcc32 Warning] uUFC.pas(48): W1000 Symbol 'FindObject' is deprecated: 'Use FindDrawable'
```

*Configs* do `Text`:

```
procedure TfrmUFC.lvwLutadoresUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  TextoIdade: TListItemText;
begin
  TextoIdade := TListItemText.Create(AItem);
  TextoIdade.Name := 'Idade';
  TextoIdade.Align := TListItemAlign.Trailing;
  TextoIdade.VertAlign := TListItemAlign.Center;
  TextoIdade.TextAlign := TTextAlign.Center;
  TextoIdade.PlaceOffset.X := -80;
  TextoIdade.PlaceOffset.Y := 0;
  TextoIdade.Font.Size := 13;
  TextoIdade.Width := 35;
  TextoIdade.Height := 18;
  TextoIdade.Visible := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Será que ele está achando a área de texto do item?
Tente usar algo do tipo:

```
ListView1.Items[0].Objects.TextObject.Text := BindSourceDB.DataSet.FieldByName('IDADE').AsString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Filipe,

Em relação ao Warning do compilador, "FindDrawable" é utilizado quando você já tem o componente Text na tela e deseja buscá-lo para alterar alguma propriedade. Ex:

```
TListItemTextButton(Aitem.Objects.FindDrawable('Btn1')).Text = 'xxxx';
```

Não é o seu caso, pode ignorar esse warning.

Olhando seu código, o comando abaixo faz com que seu objeto fique fora da tela:

```
PlaceOffset.X := -80;
```

Tente utilizar assim:

```
PlaceOffset.X := 0;
```

Outro detalhe, você precisa setar a propriedade Text para sair escrito alguma coisa na tela:

```
TextoIdade.Text := 'Agora Vai!';
```

Comment: Não foi não, como faço para criar um ItemObject.Item do tipo Idade via código? Aparentemente não está criando. Por exemplo, tem Item, Detail porém Idade não tá, e eu quero criar, receber esse idade e adicioná-lo ao ListView.

Comment: Filipe, para adicionar um novo campo, não utilize o evento "UpdateObjects". Você precisa disparar isso de outro lugar, tipo um clique em algum botão. Aí vc faz um loop na sua listview e vai adicionando o novo Text. Ex:

for i := 0 to listview.Items.Count - 1 do
begin
     txt := TListItemText.Create(listview.Items[i]);
     txt.Text := 'abc';
     ...
end;

Comment: @Heber coloque esse exemplo na resposta. Sem formatação para código fica difícil para o usuário Filipe utilizar esse exemplo corretamente, se quiser ressaltar isso na reposta utilize [EDIT].

Comment: @Paz não entendi.. o código está formatado na resposta.